# A book suitable for self-study ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, book-recommendation

I am now planning to self-study ODE, and I want a textbook that explains things clearly. After searching on this site, I find three books that are frequently reccommended: 1.Tenenbaum & Pollard  2.Coddington  3.F.Simmons

However, I would like to know the difference between these books. Are they at the same level? Or do they focus more on theory or on computation?

Also, I want a book that deals with numerical solutions (not just having one chapter on it).

Comment: _Exploring ODEs_ by Trefethen et al. might be a good complement, though surprisingly for a book by a renowned numerical analyst it’s very light on numerics. Still, it’s great on intuition and very clearly written. Also it’s free, so that’s never hurt https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/ExplODE/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Hairer, Norsett, Wanner *Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I* (Springer)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540566700).

It is very numerical-oriented but its first chapter (120 pages!) deals with the theory of ODEs.